# Browser app for editing excel files by formular

Tags: microsoft-excel, editor, office365

I have an large excel file with a lot of different tabs in microsoft excel (laying in OneDrive). I want to create some formulars (viewing and writing data in a dialog in a structured way) to make editing and viewing easier and more structured (like any web app that saves data somewhere, just with excel as database).

For example: I have a large table with persons. I got my main tab with main information and some sub-tabs with additional information. I'm currently gathering it over table formulas but this only solves the problem of viewing (and it's not really nice).

It would be really nice to make everyone editing and viewing only over those formulars.

Do you know anything? Is this possible? I have not found anything so far.